# Unable to retrieve source after successful authorization in VSCode

Tags: apex, vs-code

I created a project with manifest. When I right click on package.xml and click 'Retrieve source', VSCode is repeatedly giving the following error even after successful authorization of the org:
**ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  core_1.fs.fileExists is not a function.**

This is happening only on few projects. When I try to authorize other orgs from the same project, even then it gives the same error.

Any ideas?  I have run sfdx update multiple times on the terminal and still no luck.
Alternatively, may I know how to reach the vscode support team?

Comment: I used to have a similar issue and ended up being a Lightning Component (aura) that did not have a .cmp in the bundle.
Try reducing the component types you are fetching. Try "just" apexClass, then add VF pages, etc. one type at a time so you could see if any of them is causing the issue. If so... then you could try to narrow down the list in halves (bi-section) until you find it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it did not work. How can I reach VS code team for help?